# Django - How to load app template files properly

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django by following the book Building Django 2.0 Web Applications and everything worked up until now. The project is called config and there is one app which is called core. The app (core) has it's own templates directory (config/core/templates) and it's own urls.py file (config/core/urls.py) which is loaded by the root urls.py file (config/config/urls.py). What happens when I run the server and visit one of the core URLs, is this:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /movies

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/sugarcane/projects/config/templates/core/movie_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/sugarcane/projects/config/core/templates/core/movie_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/sugarcane/projects/config/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/core/movie_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/sugarcane/projects/config/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/core/movie_list.html (Source does not exist)
```

The template file it's looking for is actually:
/home/sugarcane/projects/config/core/templates/movie_list.html

Why is it looking in the wrong directories?

Here are the urls.py files:

**config/core/urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'core'
urlpatterns = [
    path('movies', views.MovieList.as_view(), name='MovieList'),
]
```

and

**config/config/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

import core.urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(core.urls, namespace='core')),
]
```

In **settings.py**, I got this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            ...
        },
    },
]
```

I read that **'APP_DIRS': True** tells django to look in each app directory for a templates directory. The issue in my case is it's looking for templates/core which doesn't exist. Why is it searching for the core subdirectory?

An obvious solution is to put the movie_list.html template file into config/core/templates/core, I'm just wondering why the book told me to put it directly into config/core/templates. Maybe this is because the book is written for Django 2.0, but I'm using Django 3.0?

Comment: Add slash at the end of movies in URL  `urlpatterns = [
    path('movies/', views.MovieList.as_view(), name='MovieList'),
]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the app url file inside colon

```
path('', include('core.urls')),
```

and you pattern should like like this

```
path('movies/', views.MovieList.as_view(), name='MovieList'),
```